# Is it possible to see how many items there are in FB graph (without paging them all)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm requesting this:
https://graph.facebook.com//likes
and I'd like to know how many items there are so that I can parallelize page requests.

For example, if there were 5000 items, I might make 5 calls w/ 1000 items per page.

I see there's limit/offset, but I don't see a way to know how many pages to request without trying serially.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try using fql to get the like_count or something similar to that. I am not quite certain if it will definitely work.

I had once used a query like this https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid={any id} which gets the friend_count and it surprisingly worked.

Sadly fql is not so well documented, and trial and error is how I got the above.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at the user FQL table yet.  This will do: SELECT likes_count FROM user WHERE uid = <user whose likes you are counting>

Comment: Also, for the record, FQL is documented here, and I think the docs aren't too bad: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ and the user table in particular: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/  I had previously shied from using FQL because I thought it was deprecated, but that was incorrect: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/

Answer (score 0):

If you give a massive number as the limit in the request you should be able to retrieve all the likes for a user...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?format=json&limit=10000000
```

Ten million likes...shudder...

You can use [The Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test this behavior.

Comment: That's pretty weird.  I'd still like to parallelize if possible, but I think this is a decent hack of it's not possible to get # of pages.  I also wonder if this would actually work - I imagine there's some internally-imposed limit to page size, and it's just not hit here because the actual # is under that limit in this case.

Comment: I guess so.  Luckily for me I simply dont like that many things ;)  Seems logical that there would be a limit to this - same as there is a limit for number of friends (5000) if I recall...